# Como tratar o retorno de arquivos(PDF) em uma AJAX call?

Tags: html, ajax, django, pdf

Fiz um código que seleciona os documentos que estão em um banco **FTP** e ao clicar em baixar ele executa uma **AJAX** call para o **DJANGO** onde eu chamo o **FTP** novamente, baixo o arquivo e envio de volta para o **AJAX**. Porem não consigo achar como tratar o arquivo **.PDF**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda não descobri o por que o **AJAX** está tratando como `error` e não como `sucess`. Eu deveria estar definindo o `dataType` de forma diferente? Ou tratando a reponse no Django?

O que quero fazer é, selecionar o arquivo que o usuário deseja baixar, puxa-lo no ftp e baixar na máquina do usuário.

Segue os códigos:

**AJAX**:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"{% url 'action_documents' %}",
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'documentos[]': documentos,
            'action': action,
    },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Sucess', data);
            result = 'S U C E S S O';
            // Tentando inserir o pdf em algum lugar para confimar que ele está -
            // chegando no Front End
            let html = ajax.decode(data.responseText).html;
            $('#main1').append(html);
            //ajax.get('pageContent').update(html);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            # o Ajax está saindo aqui
            console.log('Erro nos Documentos --> ', response);
            result = 'E R R O';
        }
    });
```

**DJANGO**:

```
if request.is_ajax:
    documentos = request.GET.get('documentos[]')
    # name é meramente ilustrativo
    name = documentos[1]
    ftp = logar_ftp()
    try:
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + name, buffer.write)
        buffer.seek(0)
        # sending response
        response = HttpResponse(buffer, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + name + '"'
    except IOError:
        # handle file not exist case here
        response = HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>File not exist</h1>')
else:
    response = HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Request Ajax Error</h1>')
return response
```

- Como eu devo efetuar a `request` de download na máquina do usuário?!

Answer (score -1):

O Ajax, é uma maneira de obter dados de um servidor sem a necessidade de recarregar a página, porém ele espera receber do servidor um JSON com dados.
Você pode salvar o arquivo no seu servidor e mandar como resposta para o Ajax um objeto JSON com o link para fazer o download, e no success voce USA `window.location = data.url`.

No entanto seu servidor pode ficar muito lotado com arquivos, você pode agendar uma tarefa no seu servidor para limpar a determinada pasta e apagar os arquivos do dia anterior.

Comment: Ou então cogite a opção de fazer a request sem ser com Ajax, usando um get padrão.

Comment: Sim, mas no caso os dados estão em um FTP e não há possibilidade de colocá-los no banco pois precisaria mudar toda a estrutura do mesmo. Li em vários lugares que não se coloca regras de negócios no front end(e me deram dicas sobre isso também), então sempre uso Ajax para levar ao Django e tratar as regras lá.
Por isso estou tentando enviar o arquivo via ajax visto que sempre serão arquivos não pesados de PDF. E o que seria esse ''get padrão'' que você comentou?!
Outro detalhe, tentei utilizar via link porem iria precisar de login e senha entre outros detalhes que quero evitar...